# Scipy: poisson fit not working on particular data set

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I wrote a script to fit poisson distribution which seems to work well with a data set generated using python's random.poisson but it does't work on the data set I need to fit.
Script is:

```
In [6]: from scipy.misc import factorial

In [7]: from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

In [8]: import numpy as np

In [9]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


In [11]: def poisson(k, lambd):
   ....:     print(lambd)
   ....:     return(lambd**k/factorial(k))*np.exp(-lambd)
```

Data is :

```
In [12]: x = [ 0.0036533, 0.00972361, 0.01579392, 0.02186422, 0.02793453, 0.03400484, 0.04007515, 0.04614546, 0.05221577, 0.05828608, 0.06435639, 0.0704267, 0.07649701, 0.08256731, 0.08863762]

In [13]: y =[ 0.64005518, 0.10825634, 0.05954099, 0.04330254, 0.03383011, 0.02165127, 0.02435768, 0.01623845, 0.01082563, 0.00676602, 0.00947243, 0.00947243, 0.00270641, 0.00405961, 0.00947243]

In [18]: popt, pcov = curve_fit(poisson, x, y)
```

So the problem is that best value of lambd found by this scipt(=2.82) is much higher than it should be. 
Can someone help please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Poisson distribution is a [**discrete probability distribution**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). As such it is not appropriate for non-discrete (i.e. non-integer) numbers in your `x` variables array.

The reason that it works for random data provided via `random.poisson` is that this data will be discrete, not continuous.

You should pick an alternative distribution that is [continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Continuous_distributions).

Comment: The [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) in particular is often used as a continuous approximation to a Poisson distribution